# Can I use if statement on list of values from SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement

I want to write a piece of code where I want to import the files from a SQLite database and then check if there is already a record that has some same attributes and in that case I want to not run the part of my if statement.

```
        for entry in entries:
            if beer.name not in entries[3]:
                print(f'New beer found: {beer.name}')
                print(f'Beer price: {beer.price}')
                beer.rating, beer.unt_id, beer.style = untappd_scraper(beer)
                if beer.unt_id is not entry[4]:
                    if site == "Hopt":
                        c.execute("INSERT INTO beers VALUES (:a, :b, :c, :g, :e, :f)", {'a': beer.name, 'b': beer.style, 'c': beer.rating,'g': beer.unt_id, 'e': beer.price, 'f': ''})
                        # conn.commit()
                    elif site == "Beerdome":
                        c.execute(
                            "INSERT INTO beers VALUES (:a, :b, :c, :g, :e, :f)", {'a': beer.name, 'b': beer.style, 'c': beer.rating, 'g': beer.unt_id, 'e': '', 'f': beer.price})
                        # conn.commit()
                conn.commit()
```

This does not seem to work, since the beer just keeps on being added, even tho its already multiple times in the list.
So how can I change this code to make it work?

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer.It still adds the same beer over and over again, after some time it decides to skip to a new beer tho. Don't understand why it does recognize it after somewhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the questions looks as if a database table has been queried, and now each row is being checked to see if it matches the details of a beer.  Typos aside this is unlikely to work because a new beer row will be inserted if *any* of the rows don't match the beer.

Assuming the table looks a bit like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE beers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    unt_id INTEGER)
```

we can get the details of the beer, then query to see if there is a matching row, and insert if no row is found, like this:

```py
# Let's assume we have got a beer name AND unt_id.
name, unt_id = some_function_that_gets_beer_details()

cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(1) FROM beers WHERE name = ? AND unt_id = ?""", (name, unt_id))
count, = cur.fetchone()
if count == 0:
    # Beer not found, do insert
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO beers (name, unt_id) VALUES (?, ?)""", (name, unt_id))
    conn.commit()
```

This works pretty well, but if more than one person is running the program, it's possible that a duplicate beer could be added by inserting in between the query and the insert (this is known as a race condition).  We can prevent this by adding a *constraint* to the table, , requiring that the combination of `name` and `unt_id` be *unique*.  The DDL for the table would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE beers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    unt_id INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT uniq_name_unt UNIQUE (name, unt_id))
```

Or an existing table could be updated with this SQL:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_name_unt ON beers (name, unt_id)
```

Now the code can insert the data without checking, so there is no longer a race condition.  But the code must handle the error that occurs if the beer is already present in the table.

```py
try:
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO beers (name, unt_id) VALUES (?, ?)""", ('IPA', 1))
    conn.commit()
except sqlite3.IntegrityError: 
    conn.rollback()
    print(f'Beer {name}-{unt_id} already exists!')
```

Comment: Your last couple lines of code (with some tweaking) seem to work :) Amazing!
Thanks for explaining and helping me out :)